# Tidytext error '~/Library/Caches/textdata/nrc/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-v0.92/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-Wordlevel-v0.92.txt' does not exist

Tags: r, tidytext

I tried to use `tidytext` to do sentiment analysis

```
library(tidytext)
get_sentiments("nrc")
```

but it gives me an error:

> Error:
> '~/Library/Caches/textdata/nrc/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-v0.92/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-Wordlevel-v0.92.txt'
> does not exist.

I have then tried to install the following packages from github

```
library(remotes)
install_github("EmilHvitfeldt/textdata")
install_github("juliasilge/tidytext")
```

and I still receive the same error.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like something went wrong with downloading and then unpacking the NRC sentiment lexicon. You could try going to that path and deleting the `NRC-Emotion-Lexicon` directory, and then attempting to use the lexicon again to re-prompt the download afresh.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because the file downloaded in another folder than the one specified in the subfunction. Thus, changing the path solved it for me.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(textdata)
library(readr)
library(utils)

# check the error
get_sentiments("nrc") # select 1: will throw error but data still has been downloaded
# where is the file, then?
textdata::lexicon_nrc(return_path = T) # it's here
folder_path <- "~/Library/Caches/textdata/nrc"

# the problem is that the default path is wrong, so we have to adjust it
system(paste0("mkdir ", file.path(folder_path, "NRC-Emotion-Lexicon/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-v0.92")))
system(paste0("cp ", file.path(folder_path, "NRC-Emotion-Lexicon/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-Wordlevel-v0.92.txt"), " ", file.path(folder_path, "NRC-Emotion-Lexicon/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-v0.92/")))

# now we have to process the nrc data using a slightly modified version of the subfunction detailed in the original function from the textdata-package: https://github.com/EmilHvitfeldt/textdata/blob/main/R/lexicon_nrc.R
name_path <- file.path(folder_path, "NRCWordEmotion.rds")
# slightly modified version:
process_nrc <- function(folder_path, name_path) {
  data <- read_tsv(file.path(
    folder_path,
    "NRC-Emotion-Lexicon/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-v0.92/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-Wordlevel-v0.92.txt"
  ),
  col_names = FALSE, col_types = cols(
    X1 = col_character(),
    X2 = col_character(),
    X3 = col_double()
  )
  )
  data <- data[data$X3 == 1, ]
  data <- tibble(
    word = data$X1,
    sentiment = data$X2
  )
  write_rds(data, name_path)
}

process_nrc(folder_path, name_path) # process

# check if you now have access to the lexicon
get_sentiments("nrc") 
# now you can load it with tidytext :)
```